# Retrieving data from a one-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to retrieve data from a one-to-many relationship, in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Let's say I have two tables Posts and Category with the following attributes:

posts
-id
-title
-category_id

category
-id
-name
-author

I want to grab posts that belong to a category and grab the values of .name and .author from the category.
This is what I have in the model:

```
public IQueryable<Post> GetPosts()
{
    return from post in db.Posts
            join categories in FindCategories()
            on categories.id equals post.category_id
            select new
            {
                title = post.title,
                name = categories.name,
                author = categories.author
            };
    }
```

And in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var allposts = postRepository.GetPosts().ToList();
    return View(allposts);
}
```

The model complaints that it can't convert and IQueryable of Anonymous type into an IQueryable < Post >. I suspect it's because I'm doing Select new { }, but I'm not sure.
If I do IQueryable only then I don't have the ToList() method available in the view.

So, I'm lost. Can you help? 
(an by the way, I'm a complete newbie at this asp.net mvc thing.)

Comment: Why does the category have an author?  Shouldn't it be the post that has an author?

Comment: The problem isn't MVC, it's you Linq code. You are creating an anonymous type ( select new { title... } ) which isn't the Post object that you are trying to return as an IQueryable entity set (IQueryable<Post>). You need to define another entity, say "PostForDisplay" that has title, name and author as properties and use select new PostForDisplay { title... etc } and set the return type as IQueryable<PostForDisplay>. I'm not even going to get into the logic for the structure you have defined but I do agree with @AdamRalph above.

Comment: @Lazarus Thanks very much. That helped me a lot. I, for some reason, believed that I could get away by creating these classes "on the fly".

@AdamRalph Yes, you're right, it doesn't make a lot of sense that category has an author. The model has other things, as I was editing the content for the question, I made the mistake of writing that in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been answered by Lazarus in the comments.  Your method declaration states a return type of IQueryable of Post types

```
public IQueryable<Post> GetPosts() { //...
```

But your linq projects to an anonymous type and returns an IQueryable of anonymous types

```
select new { //anonymous type
  title = post.title,
  name = categories.name,
  author = categories.author
};  // = IQueryable<SomeCompilerGeneratedTypeNameHere>
```

You need to define a new type

```
public class PostDisplay {
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

then in your code return an IQueryable of that type

```
public IQueryable<PostDisplay> GetPosts() {
  return from post in db.Posts
         join categories in FindCategories()
         on categories.id equals post.category_id
         select new PostDisplay {
                    Title = post.title,
                    Name = categories.name,
                    Author = categories.author
                  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're trying to use a var outside of the scope of a single method. In your projection stage try newing-up a Post object rather than an anonymous type. e.g.

```
public IQueryable<Post> GetPosts()
{
return from post in db.Posts
                join categories in FindCategories()
                on categories.id equals post.category_id
                select new Post()
                {
                        title = post.title,
                        name = categories.name,
                        author = categories.author
                };
}
```

Comment: If I do this, the issue is that the model Post does not contain a definition for "name" or "author"...

Comment: What's the definition of your Post class?